# Opening Explorer close if Explorer already opened on current directory

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, explorer

I have a Python script that parses an XML file into Prolog files which are saved in a directory. At the end of the parsing, I want to open the output directory.

The problem is that if explorer is already opened on the current directory (which is often the case as you have to double click the script in explorer to launch it), explorer will open on the directory and close instantly. Note that this doesn't happen if no explorer windows are opened on the current directory...

I tried every way to open it with `subprocess.Popen`, `os.startfile`, `os.system` but it's always the same.

```
# Works if explorer not opened on current directory, else don't work.
import subprocess
import os
p = subprocess.Popen('C:\Windows\EXPLORER.EXE /n /cwd="' +
                     os.getcwd() + os.sep + directory + '"')
p.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows (I'm assuming you are because you referred to Explorer), this should work:

```
import os
os.startfile('.')
```

You did mention that you tried using `os.startfile` already- what arguments were you using? Perhaps that was the problem?

Comment: I'm a bit embarrassed because I launched my script again and now it works. The thing is that the problem may occur again and as I don't know the causes, i can't solve it as well as help people in the same case... I'll write it here if I find a solution...
EDIT : The issue seems to occur when I try to open a directory that was already opened, it close it and didn't want to open it anymore (I'm looping on my main and the first occurrence open the explorer the second open and close instantly an other explorer and close the first one and then every occurrence open and close instantly the explorer)

Comment: Ah, I see. If it's in a loop, I'd guess your problem is that it's executing too fast- Explorer needs a bit of time to finish opening or closing a window, but it's being called again before it can finish it. I'd try adding a delay somewhere in the loop to give Explorer more time between calls. I didn't have any problems executing the same thing on multiple times- it only opened one Explorer window, and just refocused on that window when the next call was made. I was doing it by hand in the terminal, though, so I bet the speed of the script is to blame.